# Is it possible to set the color of a ScrollWindow?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk2, gtkscrolledwindow

I have the following code,:

```
GdkColor color;
color.red = 0x0;
color.green = 0x0;
color.blue = 0x0;

gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
window = gtk_dialog_new ();
gtk_widget_modify_bg(window, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);
gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "GtkScrolledWindow example");
gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 0);
gtk_widget_set_size_request (window, 300, 300);
gtk_window_fullscreen (GTK_WINDOW(window));
scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new (NULL, NULL);
gtk_widget_modify_bg(scrolled_window, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (scrolled_window), 10);
gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_window), GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS);
gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (GTK_DIALOG(window)->vbox), scrolled_window, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
gtk_widget_show (scrolled_window);
outside = gtk_table_new (10, 10, FALSE);
gtk_table_set_row_spacings (GTK_TABLE (outside), 10);
gtk_table_set_col_spacings (GTK_TABLE (outside), 10);
gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_window), outside);
gtk_widget_modify_bg(scrolled_window, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
gtk_widget_modify_bg(outside, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
gtk_widget_show (outside);
```

For some reason, the color of the window but not the scroll window is set to black. How can I change this?

Comment: Gtk2 is fast becoming obsolete. You should start coding in Gtk3 and use CSS.

Comment: @theGtknerd that's the standard at the place I code. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is a `GtkEventBox`.

```
GdkColor color;
color.red = 0x0;
color.green = 0x0;
color.blue = 0x0;

gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
window = gtk_dialog_new ();
gtk_widget_modify_bg(window, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);
gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "GtkScrolledWindow example");
gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 0);
gtk_widget_set_size_request (window, 300, 300);
gtk_window_fullscreen (GTK_WINDOW(window));
scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new (NULL, NULL);
//gtk_widget_modify_bg(scrolled_window, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (scrolled_window), 10);
gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_window), GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS);
gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (GTK_DIALOG(window)->vbox), scrolled_window, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
gtk_widget_show (scrolled_window);
outside = gtk_table_new (10, 10, FALSE);
gtk_table_set_row_spacings (GTK_TABLE (outside), 10);
gtk_table_set_col_spacings (GTK_TABLE (outside), 10);

GtkWidget *box = gtk_event_box_new();
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box), outside);
gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_window), box);
gtk_widget_modify_bg(box, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
gtk_widget_show (box);

//gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_window), outside);
//gtk_widget_modify_bg(scrolled_window, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
//gtk_widget_modify_bg(outside, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
gtk_widget_show (outside);
```

Answer (score -1):

If this is Gtk3 you should be using CSS: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html

Something like this sets the background color of all children of scrolled windows:

```
scrolledwindow * {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Obviously in real usage you would probably be more specific by giving your widget a custom class itself.

Check out the inspector too to make trying out CSS easier: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/Inspector

Comment: unfortunately this is gtk2 :(

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkThemes). Gtk+2 uses rc files and theming engines.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with setting colors programmatically.

Comment: Sure it does, you can parse any themes at runtime for both Gtk2 and Gtk3.